# Is javascript string.replace linear?

Tags: javascript, regex

is javascript's string.replace linear replacement or is there some funky optimization??  Basically, my question is that will the result of this code be numerically sequential?

```
  var index = 0;
  html = html.replace(/replaceIndex/g, function (match, capture) {
    return index++;
  });
```

I have a feeling that answer to this question will be "it depends on x" where x is firefox, chrome, v8, rhino, or etc.

Comment: What is your input string?

Comment: regexes work left to right. (unless you specify otherwise, which javascript doesn't have).

Comment: I don't have a definitive answer, but I can't imagine how it would work otherwise. Imagine `'abababa'.replace(/aba/g, ...`. Without a definitive left to right or right to left replacement the result of the output is ambiguous.

Comment: The spec is a bit dense, but I believe it specifies how matching and replacing is done: http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11

Comment: The [spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) just says "for each matched substring, call the function with the following m + 3 arguments". It doesn't say anything about what order to go in.

Comment: @DanielA.White: That just means the matches will be found in that order. It doesn't mean the replaceValue function has to be called in that order.

Comment: @user2357112: It does: [15.5.4.10.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.10)8.f.iii - you can see how `previousLastIndex` increments. You can also see it in [15.10.6.2](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.10.6.2).9. (`exec`)

Comment: @Amadan: That just specifies how matches are found, not the order in which the replaceValue function is called on the matches.

Comment: @user2357112: True. The order of function execution seems to be unspecified, which is not a good idea in a spec that is otherwise so precise. However, in every implementation the function execution order is done in the match order.

Comment: The maximum length of a string is about 150 chars, I doubt parallel replacement is required unless you'd have to to about a million of those. In which case you'd be better off scheduling the replacements themselves in parallel using parallel.js anyway.

Comment: @ShellFish 150 chars? My Firefox can have strings up to 2^28-1 chars.

Comment: Haha ok, perhaps I should update my browser then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ES5](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.5.4.11) does not seem to specify the order of the calls:

> for each matched substring, call the function with the following *m* + 3
>   arguments.

However, ES6 does. [`String.prototype.replace`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-string.prototype.replace) uses [`RegExp.prototype[@@replace]`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-regexp.prototype-@@replace) which (resumed) behaves like

> [**21.2.5.8 RegExp.prototype [ @@replace ] ( string, replaceValue
>   )**](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#sec-regexp.prototype-@@replace)
>
> - Let *S* be ToString(*string*).
> - Let *results* be a new empty List.
> - Repeat
>
>   - Let *result* be RegExpExec(*rx*, *S*).
>   - Append *result* to the end of *results*.
> - Let *accumulatedResult* be the empty String value.
> - Let *nextSourcePosition* be 0.
> - Repeat, for each *result* in *results*,
>
>   - Let *position* be ToInteger(Get(*result*, `"index"`)).
>   - Let *position* be max(min(*position*, *lengthS*), 0).
>   - Let *replValue* be Call(*replaceValue*, **undefined**, *replacerArgs*).
>   - Let *replacement* be ToString(*replValue*).
>   - If *position* ≥ nextSourcePosition, then
>
>     - NOTE *position* should not normally move backwards. If it does, it is an indication of an ill-behaving RegExp subclass or use of
>         an access triggered side-effect to change the global flag or other
>         characteristics of *rx*. In such cases, the corresponding substitution
>         is ignored.
>     - Let *accumulatedResult* be the String formed by concatenating the code units of the current value of *accumulatedResult* with the
>         substring of *S* consisting of the code units from
>         *nextSourcePosition* (inclusive) up to *position* (exclusive) and with the code units of *replacement*.
>     - Let *nextSourcePosition* be *position* + *matchLength*.
> - If *nextSourcePosition* ≥ *lengthS*, return *accumulatedResult*.
> - Return the String formed by concatenating the code units of *accumulatedResult* with the substring of *S* consisting of the code units from *nextSourcePosition* (inclusive) up through the final code
>     unit of *S* (inclusive).

Answer (score 2):

Besides someone has given you a link to ES spec, here's a simple test that you could try yourself.

If you try following code in Chrome DevTools, Firebug, or IE F12, you will see `0` for three times, and matches are in sequential order.

```
var r = /\d/g;
'a1b2c3d'.replace(r, function(m) {
  console.log(r.lastIndex, m);
});
// 0 "1"
// 0 "2"
// 0 "3"
```

That implies:

1. RE matching was actually finished before replace function called.
2. Matches are replaced one by one sequentially.

Comment: I did similar test and could see that replaces are not done parallel but sequentially.  However, my fear is that an implementation of JS will half the input and run replace in parallel when input is too big or something like that.

Comment: @coding_twinky In what scenario will it break your code? By the way, as far as I know, all major implementations (mainstream browsers and node) are doing it sequentially.

Comment: I haven't had a case where it breaks but I'm looking for an assurance for in order assumption.